# SUSE zypper doesn't take piped inputs

Tags: bash, opensuse, suse, zypper

I have a problem with SUSE 12 zypper.
I need to install an unsigned package with zypper in non-interactive mode from script.
Unfortunately, zypper version is 1.13 and there is no option for flag "--allow-unsigned-rpm". So I've been trying to "pipe" output of the printf command in to zypper, but having no luck so far :( here is an example of what I am doing:

```
printf "y\ni\n" | sudo zypper install UNSIGNED_RPM_PATH_HERE
```

What am I doing wrong? This pipe works for every other script I tried to write myself.

Comment: Why not just `sudo rpm -Uvh name.of.rpm`? Also note, this question is off-topic here (not programming related). Better asked on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It has dependencies that rpm can't easily resolve

Comment: That makes sense. `zypper` 1.14 has `--allow-unsigned-rpm`.  Do the repositories you have enabled have all the dependencies for `UNSIGNED_RPM_PATH_HERE`? And is that path a local path on your hard drive or is that a URL to so online package?

Comment: It's a local path. Yes it does have all the dependencies. Problem that I have to use zypper 1.13 and can't update it:(. I don't Control EC2 image and can't change it, So stuck with 1.13 version.

Comment: Edit `/etc/zypp/zypp.conf` and set `pkg_gpgcheck = off` will silently accept unsigned packages. The `"Signature checking"` options start about line 263 in the conf file I have. You can add temporarily at the bottom of that block. You can do `sudo vim /etc/zypp/zypp.conf` and then `/## Signature checking` to skip to the block, arrow down to the first blank line after the block and tap `i` (for insert mode) and enter `pkg_gpgcheck = off`, then hit the `[esc]` key to return to command mode and `:wq` to save and quit.